# How to use `...args` to pass many arguments to base class?

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript 2.0

```
class Parent {
    constructor(a, b, c, d, e) {
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args); // this currently fails
    }
}
```

The following looks cumbersome.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(a, b, c, d, e) {
        super(a, b, c, d, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that the complied js is just fine:

```
var Parent = (function () {
    function Parent(a, b, c, d, e) {
        console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
    }
    return Parent;
}());
var Child = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Child, _super);
    function Child() {
        var args = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            args[_i - 0] = arguments[_i];
        }
        _super.apply(this, args);
    }
    return Child;
}(Parent));
```

I'm not sure why you're getting this error.
Try [opening an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), if you do, please post the link as a comment.

---

#### Edit

Seems like this issue: [Support spread operator for arrays and tuples in function calls](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5296) is about this as well.

With regular functions you can cast them to any:

```
function fn(a, b) { }
let a = [1, 2];
fn(...a); // Error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
(fn as any)(...a); // no error
```

But you can't do that with a `super` call.
You can argue that the compiler is guarding you, the content of `...args` could have less or more values then the `Parent` constructor expects, but then this doesn't work as well:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(...args: [any, any, any, any, any]) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

Because:

> A rest parameter must be of an array type

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ says it's a compile error. "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
(parameter) args: any[]"

Comment: Yes, I know, check my revised answer